# How can I get all `apt-get` commands that I've issued since I launched a Debian server?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I need to go back to basics on a VPS but I don't want to wipe it clean.

I understand that Debian stores `apt-get` commands somewhere, but these are separated in to separate log files.

Is it possible to bring all these together to get a complete list of all `apt-get` commands that I've issued (basically so that I can reverse them)?

I am looking for this output:

```
$ blah

apt-get install libpack-4 libpack-5 libpack-6 libpack-dev
apt-get purge libpack-4
apt-get install blah-1 blah-2
apt-get purge somepack-1 
apt-get install libpack-4 libpack-5 libpack-6 libpack-dev
apt-get purge libpack-4
apt-get install blah-1 blah-2
apt-get purge somepack-1
apt-get install libpack-4 libpack-5 libpack-6 libpack-dev
apt-get purge libpack-4
apt-get install blah-1 blah-2
apt-get purge somepack-1
apt-get install libpack-4 libpack-5 libpack-6 libpack-dev
apt-get purge libpack-4
apt-get install blah-1 blah-2
apt-get purge somepack-1
```

Comment: Similar questions were asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/175504/how-do-i-get-the-history-of-apt-get-install-on-unbuntu) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/161412/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-root-main-installed-packages-on-debian).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/var/log/apt/`

There you will find the current log on `term.log` and `history.log` as long has `.gz`. files of the past months.

gunzip all the history.log files and then run this line:

```
cat history.log.* | grep Commandline |awk -F":" '{print $2}'> all_apt-get-commands.txt
```

On  the file `all_apt-get-commands.txt` you will find the list of all the commands.

Comment: Thanks but I understand that. Is there any way to compile a long list as above from these files?

Comment: @Jack I edited my answer to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

One addition to @jcbermu 's solution.

You can use `zgrep` directly on gzip-compressed **and** uncompressed files, which simplifies the full command, including gunzipping, into one line:

```
zgrep CommandLine /var/log/apt/history.log* | cut -d\  -f 2-
```

`history.log*` instead of `history.log.*` is used so the current `history.log` is also included.

To get unique lines, pipe it through `uniq`. To get lines only containing `apt-get` calls, pipe it to `grep ^apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other posts you have to look in `/var/log/apt`. To achieve what you want you can try following:

```
>| out.log; for i in $(ls -1rt $(find /var/log/apt -name '*history*')); do if [[ $i =~ \.gz$ ]]; then zgrep "Commandline" $i | awk -F': ' '{ print $2; }' >>out.log; else grep "Commandline" $i | awk -F': ' '{ print $2; }' >>out.log; fi done;
```

File out.log should contain your commands ordered by date

Answer (score 0):

You can get a log in `/var/log/apt/history.log*`. Logs are rotated regularly, so older logs may not be present anymore. Once these logs are gone, there's nothing similar. If you've had your VPS for a while, you probably won't be able to find out what was there initially.

There is little point in uninstalling packages unless you're short of disk space. If that's the problem, look for large packages that you don't need. The following command lists installed packages by increasing size:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Installed-Size;8}  ${Package}\n' | sort -n
```

If you want to know the initial configuration of that VPS, ask around the hosting provider's forums, someone will probably be able to tell you.

If you want to go to a minimal system for learning purposes, be aware that you won't learn much; but a good starting point would be to uninstall all packages whose [priority](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-priority) is required or important. This is easiest to do with [aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(software)): limit (`l`) the view to non-required/important packages with the [search term](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html) `~pstandard | ~poptional | ~pextra` and uninstall them all except the ones you absolutely need. Make sure you keep some critical packages such as `sudo` and `openssh-server` or you'll make the VPS unusable. Such experiments are best done in a virtual machine, so that you have a way to repair it or start again if you break it.